# Is the following inequality true: $x^{t}y^{1-t} \geq tx+(1-t)y$ for $t\in [0,1], x,y > 0$?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

I encountered this problem when trying to determine whether the objective function of some problem is convex. I was able to reduce the proof to the above inequality.

I have not been able to find a counter example to the inequality so I suspect it is probably true. However, I am completely stuck on how I would go about proving that this is indeed the case. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: The reversed inequality is true.  It is a generalized version of AM-GM for two variables.  That is, $$x^ty^{1-t}\leq tx+(1-t)y$$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $x,y>0$.  The equality cases are $t=0$, $t=1$, and $x=y$.  You can prove this by Jensen's inequality or just differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is true:
$$x^{t}y^{1-t} \leq tx+(1-t)y$$
since, as  the logarithm is a concave function,
$$\log(x^{t}y^{1-t})=t\log x+(1-t)\log y \leq \log\bigl(tx+(1-t)y\bigr).$$
*Note*: If  your inequality were true, it would imply $\sqrt{xy}\ge \dfrac{x+y}2$, which contradicts the AGM inequality.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\sqrt{xy}\ge\frac{x+y}{\color{#C00}{2}}$.

Comment: @robjohn: Oops. I should reread what I did write before posting! Thanks for pointing the typo!

Answer (score 1):

$x=0.1,y=1,t=0.5$ is a counterexample. Left hand side is about $0.31$, the right hand side is $0.55$

Answer (score 1):

Is

$$4^{1/2}9^{1-1/2}\ge \frac12\cdot 4+\left(1-\frac12\right)9?$$